# How to run PHP script actively on client side / client machine?

Tags: javascript, php, html, client-server

I'm trying to run a PHP script directly on the client side rather than taking request from a client to server & receiving back processed output or file. I created a PHP script which is running properly on the server side. I want to run that same PHP script on the client side as well. The PHP is not installed on the client side, it is only on the server side. Using `<object>` method I somehow managed to execute a PHP script on the client side. But it's just window or small frame that is visible on the current browser or in a page on the browser of a local machine (or client machine). So whenever PHP functions are invoked, it is executed at the server side, not on the client side.

Is there a way to execute PHP functions actually on the client side as well?

OR

Is there a way to open that entire working PHP page on the client side rather than on small window or in a frame of server page on a client browser without PHP installation?

What I tried is:

I created PHP script as **"SERVER.php"** which displays the name of all the files of a current working directory of the **SERVER machine**.

```
<?php
exec('dir', $status, $result);
var_dump($status);
?>
```

I want to get name of all the files of a current working directory but of **CLIENT machine**.
I created a html file as **"CLIENT.html"** that consists of the following code:

```
<object type="text/html" data="http://192.168.0.110:81/file2v2.php" width="800px" height="600px" style="overflow:auto;border:5px ridge blue">
</object>
```

Basically, the **object** function used in **html** contains the ***ip address*** followed by the ***port no.*** (of the Apache Server) and the ***php file name*** of the server (where php is installed and located).

Can anyone please help me how to execute PHP functions or say entire PHP scripts on the client side, or the way it can get it done.

Answer (score 1):

All clients where you want to execute PHP scripts need to have PHP installed, as well as a running webserver (if those scripts are accessed via http). There is no way around that.

One way to do it without client side code is to give your webserver SSH access to all the clients. (This means creating the user on each machine and giving it the necessary permissions). Then the server could read the visitor's IP, connect to it via SSH and read the filesystem of the client and display it in the browser. This would be a wild approach, but possible.

Check this out: https://kvz.io/blog/2007/07/24/make-ssh-connections-with-php/

It would also mean that if someone gets access to that server or can somehow exploit it, all clients are compromised as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should take a look at the difference between client-side and server-side. Take a look [here](https://techdifferences.com/difference-between-server-side-scripting-and-client-side-scripting.html), it explains a lot. 
Quote from the above link:

> Key Differences Between Server-side Scripting and Client-side Scripting
>
> 1. Server-side scripting is used at the backend, where the source code is not viewable or hidden at the client side (browser). On the other hand, client-side scripting is used at the front end which users can see from the browser.
> 2. When a server-side script is processed it communicates to the server. As against, client-side scripting does not need any server interaction.
> 3. The client-side scripting language involves languages such as HTML, CSS and JavaScript. In contrast, programming languages such as PHP, ASP.net, Ruby, ColdFusion, Python, C#, Java, C++, etc.
> 4. Server-side scripting is useful in customizing the web pages and implement the dynamic changes in the websites. Conversely, the client-side script can effectively minimize the load to the server.
> 5. Server-side scripting is more secure than client-side scripting as the server side scripts are usually hidden from the client end, while a client-side script is visible to the users.

If you want every logic done on the client-side, take a look at Angular, VueJS or just basic Javascript. But with Javascript (including Angular/VueJS/Etc.) you can not manipulate client-side files, which would be a major security issue if it was able to. To change things on the server-side, you will always need a back-end programming language like PHP, C#, Java etc. 
**Be aware that everything you do on the client-side, is visible for the client and can be changed by the client. Which makes your application vulnerable for attackers.**

To answer your question: You can't.

Comment: I'm totally with you on the JS part, however client side JS does not include the ability to read/manipulate local files. For VERY good reason, if you think about it.

Comment: @WilliamRandokun You are completely right, and I'm glad it doesn't!

Comment: @William Randokun - Thats exactly is the problem.

Comment: @Michel - Thats why I'm using php, but I can't install php on every client machine, so I'm creating a refernce of php which is used by all the clients. But not as much as flexible as it is in server side.

Comment: @David - Can you elaborate what you are trying to accomplish? Why do you want to run that PHP script on the clients? What does the script do?

Comment: @Michel - Actually I want to automate the things. Currently I'm taking files from the client side to server side using "choose file" button at client side. So every time the user has to click on "choose file" button, select the file by browsing & then have to click on "upload" button to send file from client to php server. I want to make it automatically done rather than clicking for every file to upload.

Comment: @David - Well, I don't think browsers will ever let that happen. When a website is free to choose which file is uploaded, without consent of the user, wouldn't that by a privacy infringement? Imagine if Stackoverflow would just copy your documents directory and sell it. If it are clients in a private network and you have full control over the clients, then you can easily make PHP scripts for the clients to push the file contents to your server. But without full control over the client, this is not going to work.

Comment: @Michel - Yes, it's absolutely private network. Only those clients within the same network of the server will have access to open php file using html. But how it can easily run on client side without even installing php on their machines.

Comment: @David - Well, you can perform something like William Randokun has written in his answer. But then you have to enable and set-up SSH on every client. You can do the same with FTP, but then again would you need to enable and set-up FTP on every client. I don't see how this would be possible without setting up PHP on the clients and running a little webserver on the clients or installing SSH or FTP.

Comment: @David - I just realised, maybe you can share the windows folders on the clients and let the server be able to access them. Then you can make your PHP script to get to the shared folder and access the file.

Comment: @Michel - Thanks Michel, you approach seems good but the thing is this entire  problem is occurring in a web application. So, I'm stucked, otherwise that's the best way for file sharing in a client server architecture in an intranet network.

Answer (score 0):

To run a script, you need an interpreter installed, the browser can read js script, but cannot read php script, for example.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP

Answer (score 0):

Basically, no.

But you can read about C# Blazor approach (https://dotnet.microsoft.com/apps/aspnet/web-apps/blazor) and try to implement something like this.